# How to obtain a pointer to an object just reading the target address from memory?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a variable called `target` which has value `0x52d000000938`. Its value is calculated doing `ctx + offset`. The pseudo code is

```
int offset = calculate_offset();
type_t *ctx = get_ctx();

printf("[+] ctx + offset %p\n", ctx + offset);
```

The output if ctx is `0x52d000000410` and offset `1320` I get `0x52d000000938`

```
[+] ctx + offset 0x52d000000938
```

Now if I check in `gdb` at the address `0x52d000000938` I get the following output

```
gdb> x/g 0x52d000000938
0x52d000000938: 0x00007ffff702f820
gdb>
```

Now my question is: Assuming that `0x00007ffff702f820` is pointing to an object of type `second_type_t` how can I have a pointer of type `second_type_t` pointing exactly at `0x00007ffff702f820` just reading the value at `0x52d000000938`

Comment: "The output if ctx is 0x52d000000410 and offset 1320 I get 0x52d000000938" Sure, if `type_t` is a pointer to character. Otherwise `ctx + offset` gives pointer arithmetic based on the pointed-at type and you do not get an address ending with 0x938.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add `offset` bytes to the pointer `ctx`, you can use

```
void *result = (char *) ctx + offset;
```

Note that if you merely use `ctx + offset`, this adds `offset` **elements**, instead of `offset` **bytes**, to the address. The element type used is taken from the type of `ctx`, so it is `type_t`. If the size of `type_t` is not one byte, then `(char *) ctx + offset` and `ctx + offset` produce different addresses.

Once you have the address, you apparently want to load a pointer to a `second_type_t` from that address. If the address was stored as a type `second_type_t *`, then you can load it using that type:

```
second_type_t *pointer = * (second_type_t **) result;
```

Combining these two operations, you could have:

```
second_type_t *pointer = * (second_type_t **) ((char *) ctx + offset);
```

### Caveats

These operations use pointers in ways that go beyond what the C standard guarantees, so it is possible you may have to take additional steps that guarantee the code works. For example, if the address to the `second_type_t` was stored using a type other than `second_type_t *`, the compiler might treat that store and the load above as unrelated. Discussion of these issues would depend on further context about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that the task is simply to read a 32 bit integer value from a known absolute address. Then we'd do this:

```
uint32_t val = *(uint32_t*)0x12345678u;
```

That is, cast the address to a pointer to the type we know is stored there, then de-reference it. Simply apply the same logic:

```
second_type_t* ptr = *(second_type_t**)0x52d000000938u
```

That is, cast the absolute address to a pointer to whatever type that's stored there, which happens to be a  `second_type_t*`.

---

Now this is questionable for a number of reasons:

- Unless `type_t` is an alias for a character type, then `type_t *ctx` ... `ctx + offset` with an offset of 1320 does *not* give you an address 1320 bytes further ahead. This is basic pointer arithmetic. You get the address `sizeof(type_t) * 1320` bytes further ahead.
- Furthermore, if the memory map doesn't happen to be one big array of `type_t`, we can't do pointer arithmetic like this or we invoke undefined behavior by going out of bounds of the pointed-at item. One solution to that could be to ditch the pointer arithmetic and cast the address to `uintptr_t`, then do the arithmetic on plain integers. As a bonus, that would also fix the previously mentioned bug of doing arithmetic on the wrong type. So `(uintptr_t)ctx + offset`.
- We need to know that alignment is ok and what's actually stored at the address is indeed a `second_type_t*`, or otherwise we invoke all manner of undefined behavior.
- Reading an absolute address means we should almost always `volatile` qualify the read, in case we are dealing with hardware addresses or other things that may change outside of the compiler's knowledge.

Answer (score -2):

It is implementation and hardware-defined but it is quite common in the low level programming.

```
typedef struct
{
    int x,y,z;
    float a,b,c;
} second_type_t;

#define SECOND_TYPE_PTR(addr) ((volatile second_type_t *)(*(uintptr_t *)(addr)))

//if the address of the second_type_t is side effects prone 

#define SECOND_TYPE_PTR_SE(addr) ((volatile second_type_t *)(*(volatile uintptr_t *)(addr)))

int main(void)
{
    second_type_t str = {.x = 1, .y = 2, .z = 3, .a = 5.0, .b = 6.0, .c = 7.0};

    uintptr_t str_addr = (uintptr_t)&str;
    uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t)&str_addr;

    printf("x = %d\n", SECOND_TYPE_PTR(addr) -> x);
    printf("y = %d\n", SECOND_TYPE_PTR(addr) -> y);
    printf("z = %d\n", SECOND_TYPE_PTR(addr) -> z);
    printf("a = %f\n", SECOND_TYPE_PTR(addr) -> a);
    printf("b = %f\n", SECOND_TYPE_PTR(addr) -> b);
    printf("c = %f\n", SECOND_TYPE_PTR(addr) -> c);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8aMcc5Ers

or more generic:

```
#define GET_PTR(addr, type) ((volatile type *)(*(volatile uintptr_t *)(addr)))
```

and usage:

```
    printf("x = %d\n", GET_PTR(addr, second_type_t) -> x);
    printf("c = %f\n", GET_PTR(addr, second_type_t) -> c);
```

or a very safe version:

```
volatile second_type_t *getPTR(uintptr_t addr)
{
    volatile second_type_t *st_ptr;
    memcpy(&st_ptr, (void *)addr, sizeof(st_ptr));
    return st_ptr;
}
```

Comment: `((second_type_t *)(*(uintptr_t *)(addr)))` doesn't make any sense and is undefined behavior. It should simply be `(second_type_t*)addr`.

Comment: @Lundin no. The address of `the second_type_t` object is stored in the location given by the integer, So you need to read this address form that location first. Reading the example code would help understand the idea. `addr` **is not** the address of the `second_type_t` object!!

Comment: I know that, that's not what I'm remarking about. What's stored on the address is not a `uintptr_t` object either, but a `second_type_t*`. These types do not alias so you invoke a strict aliasing violation.  Lets say you modify the object through `GET_PTR(addr, second_type_t) -> x = 123;`. The compiler is now free to assume that `str.x` remains 1, because you only accessed it through an lvalue of type `uintpr_t`. You convert that read value into the correct pointer type after reading it, but then the UB has already occurred.

Comment: Was kind of hard to provoke UB with any of the mainstream compilers, but here is an example to illustrate a strict aliasing bug based of an incorrect `uintptr_t` lvalue access. https://godbolt.org/z/GGx49fPdj

Comment: @Lundin indeed I forgot `volatile` https://godbolt.org/z/EeG75zvc8

Comment: Volatile doesn't make it any less undefined, it just blocks the optimizations that in some cases would make UB manifest itself much easier.